# How to classify instances according to its relative feature value within a group of points?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering

Thanks everyone for viewing my question!

My real data is very complicated, but briefly it can be formalized as this problem below: currently I have many groups of datapoints, each consisting of 5 datapoints, I want to design an algorithm to label each of the 5 points in a group from 0~4 (Input is a group of 5 points, output is their labels 0~4). On a 2d scatter plot, the problem is like:

```
Train Set
| name | feature1 | feature2 |  group   |   label  |
| ---- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| G1L0 |    1     |    1     |   1      |    0     |
| G1L1 |    4     |    3     |   1      |    1     |
| G1L2 |    4     |    5     |   1      |    2     |
| G1L3 |    2     |    4.5   |   1      |    3     |
| G1L4 |    6     |    5     |   1      |    4     |
| ---- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| G2L0 |    2.6   |    0.8   |   2      |    0     |
| G2L1 |    3.9   |    3.5   |   2      |    1     |
| G2L2 |    3.4   |    4.5   |   2      |    2     |
| G2L3 |    2.3   |    5.5   |   2      |    3     |
| G2L4 |    5.6   |    4.5   |   2      |    4     |
Test Set
| ---- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| G3L0 |    2.1   |    1.1   |   3      |    0     |
| G3L1 |    4.3   |    3.7   |   3      |    1     |
| G3L2 |    4.9   |    5.4   |   3      |    2     |
| G3L3 |    3.6   |    5.3   |   3      |    3     |
| G3L4 |    6.5   |    5.5   |   3      |    4     |
```

The key issue is that the classification of each of the 5 datapoints **depends on the information of other points within the group**, globally the data suffers greatly from variation of the data, specifically, if I train a traditional classifier on my train set it may end up like:
[image]
But if I simply use this classifier to predict the test set there will be problem:
[image]

This is because globally the variation across different groups is huge, but within a single group I can easily classify them manually. Experience is something like "Three points at top, from left to right they are label 3, label 2, label 4, then for two points at below they are label 0 (left), label 1 (right). Also, the classifier may label two points in a same group as 3, but this is impossible to happen (We must have label 0~4 in a group).

I know this problem can be easily solved by normalization within the group, however, my real problem is 10-dimensional with more than 15 datapoints, and there are different types of variations and **normalization by group is basically not feasible as I tried for a week.**

Therefore, is there any way I can utilize the idea of "considering the position of other points in a group"? That is, encode the relative position information into a feature?

Thanks so much in advance, any answers or hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you plase explain what is to be predicted? The label or the group? Or both?

Comment: Hello @cdalitz, the problem is updated for clarity. The input is a group of 5 points, the output is their labels 0~4 with no repeated ones.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious approach would be to subtract the group mean (in 10 dimensions) from the features in each group and then use these points as input for a classifier. This assumes that the shape of the groups is similar for all groups. If they vary in scale, you could additionally normalize by the standard deviation or diameter of the group.

If the labels are ordered, i.e. $0<1<2<3<4$, an alternative approach would be a mixed ordinal regression model with the group id as a "random effect". This should figure out the shift on itself during training.

Comment: Hi @cdalitz, thanks for your answer. I once considered this approach. As what I've thought, this requires a strict order of subtraction, for example input feature for point 0 should be (point0-point1, point0-point2, ..., point0-point4), and the result will totally mess up if the order is changed. But I am not sure if this order can be fixed in the case that we do not know which point has which label.

Comment: I also tried to fix this order along an axis, or even along all the axes (like a kd-tree sorting), but unfortunately none of them can ensure a fixed order :(

Comment: No, what I meant was: let $\mu$ be the mean feature *vector* within a group. Then the transformed corordinates of point $p_i$ are $p_i - \mu$. I will edit my answer to include an alternative approach, if the labels are orderd (which you apparently assume).

Comment: Ohh I got your idea, I will go learn more about the model you mentioned! Thanks, I will upvote once I have enough reputation to do so..